# Got empty license reports with hierynomus' gradle license plugin

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, licensing, gradle-plugin

I'm making two android apps on a Gradle project and managing dependency licenses with Hierynomus' [gradle license plugin](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin).
Then, I executed following commands:

```sh
$ ./gradlew downloadLicenses
$ cat ./build/reports/license/dependency-license.json
```

But the generated license reports are empty.

```
{"dependencies":[]}
```

I tried to fix the problem with the documents below:

- https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin/issues/81
- https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin/issues/103
- https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin/issues/137
- https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin/issues/174

but I couldn't resolve the problem.

Next, I tried to execute the task with `--refresh-dependencies` and `--rerun-tasks` options. Sadly, the problem hadn't fixed.

Those are my build scripts:

```
// build.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    ext.kotlin_coroutine_version = '1.1.1'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.hierynomus.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.12.1'
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.21.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/spek" }
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'
    apply plugin: 'com.github.hierynomus.license'

    downloadLicenses {
        includeProjectDependencies = true
        dependencyConfiguration = 'implementation'
        ext.apacheTwo = license('Apache License, Version 2.0', 'https://opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0')
        ext.bsd = license('BSD License', 'https://opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license')
        aliases = [
            (apacheTwo): [
                'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0',
                'Apache 2',
                'Apache License Version 2.0',
                'Apache License, Version 2.0',
                'Apache License 2.0',
                license('Apache License', 'https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0')
            ],
            (bsd): [
                'BSD',
                license('New BSD License', 'https://opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license')
            ]
        ]
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
// app/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xyz.tech-frodo.testFirebaseApp.console"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        lintConfig file("lint.xml")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:1.12.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.4'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlin_coroutine_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:$kotlin_coroutine_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlin_coroutine_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

```
// client/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xyz.tech-frodo.testFirebaseApp.client"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlin_coroutine_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:$kotlin_coroutine_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlin_coroutine_version"
    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:1.12.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.9.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.spek:spek-api:1.1.5'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:1.1.5'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.1.0'
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

No doubt I expected dependencies license reports of my project were generated under `${PROJECT_ROOT}/build/reports/license/`. I found the reports are generated, however, those were empty.

Thanks!

Comment: ever resolve this? DId you file a report with the plugin author? Try another plugin?

Comment: Yes, finally I couldn't resolve the problem. And I opened an issue to the plugin's repo, but still not resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with version 0.15.0 [Fix getting licenses on Android](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin/pull/184).

For me, it worked with version 0.14.0 and some additional configurations:

```
// buil.gradle root
plugins {
   id "com.github.hierynomus.license" version "0.14.0"
}

downloadLicenses {
   dependencyConfiguration = 'implementation'
   includeProjectDependencies = true
}

// build.gradle app
apply plugin: 'com.github.hierynomus.license'
configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
configurations.api.setCanBeResolved(true)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. I have java based spring boot project. After lot of trail and error, It worked finally. But configurations.api results in build error. So I removed that configurations.api line and then removed the apply plugin line too, still it worked. I have used gradle 6.7 version.

Comment: Agree with post above (mohan), same, had to remove "api" line.... but this worked when other suggestions did not work... (Appreciated).    I also was able to get it to work with both Gradle 6.8 and 7.2.

Comment: Also, for those who want to modernize...  I was also able to use the latest 0.16.1 with Gradle 7.2 which should work on its own, but did not, until the above additions were added (except having to remove the api line)